# Symfony4 guard authenticator doesn't work, no errors returned when log in

Tags: authentication, symfony4, symfony-guard

I am currently building a Symfony4 application with a custom guard authenticator. But I have a problem, when I try to log in with the login form I am not authenticated and I got no error message.

I have tried many things, like changing supports function code or the login form but cannot solve the problem.

My configuration is the "out of the box" from make:auth command.

If someone can tell me where I made something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Security controller

```php
<?php

//[...]
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }
}
```

Security

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern: ^/login$
            anonymous: ~

        main:
            #anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LdapCustomAuthenticator
```

Login form

```html
<form method="post">
    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
    <input type="email" value="{{ last_username }}" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
           value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
    >

    {#
        Uncomment this section and add a remember_me option below your firewall to activate remember me functionality.
        See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html

        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
    #}

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
        Sign in
    </button>
</form>
```

Custom authenticator

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LdapCustomAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        echo "get credentials";
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        // Check the user's password or other credentials and return true or false
        // If there are no credentials to check, you can just return true
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: check the credentials inside '.__FILE__);
        return true;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('default'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your custom authenticator? It's not clear that you are extending the `AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator`, and if so then you are missing a few methods.

Comment: I have edit the question with the full custom authenticator

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to delete `login` firewall from security.yaml? That should work. Because when you try to login you are on that firewall and there is no guard configured. Keep there only `dev` and `main`.

As you said in comment you got infinite redirects, it is caused that you did not allowed it in access control. Check my edited code

```
security:
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

    main:
      #anonymous: true
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - App\Security\LdapCustomAuthenticator

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    # You can use it also for different roles, maybe you need also route for all check comments (be careful with order)
    #- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
    #- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

Comment: When I delete `login` firewall I can't see the login page because of infinite redirection. `access_control` part seems not to work.

Comment: Check updated response. You did not allowed to access login page to unauthorised users. that is reason for redirects